# Where has my reasoning on this probability problem gone wrong?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

15 people are randomly assigned to three cars, each holding 4, 5, and 6 people respectively. The owners of the cars are among the 15, and will be randomly assigned to one of the cars. What is the probability that each owner gets assigned to his or her own car?

My thought process: 
The total number of ways to assign 15 people to the three cars is 15!/(4!5!6!). 
The number of ways to assign 12 people to each of the three cars (leaving room for the three owners) is 12!/(3!4!5!).
There are 3! ways to fill the remaining seats with the 3 owners, only one of which lands each owner with his or her car. For that one option, there are the same 12!/(3!4!5!) ways to fill the cars with the 12 other people. Thus, there are 12!/(3!4!5!) ways to have each car filled and have the owners assigned to their car.

Therefore the probability is [12!/(3!4!5!)]/[15!/(4!5!6!)].

Comment: why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the answer, nor with the method.  Of course, the expression you wrote can be greatly simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong in your argument, but the simplest way is to seat the owners properly first, it doesn't matter where the rest go

Thus $Pr = \frac4{15}\cdot\frac5{14}\cdot\frac6{13}$

Comment: why $\frac{5}{11}$ ?

Comment: @Carry on Smiling: Thanks, amended.

Comment: ok, but that is the same number OP got.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: I included that when I amended.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry about that,+1.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the owners are one per car, but the problem statement does not say that.  You could have all three owners in the six passenger car, for example. Your calculation does not include that possibility.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The problem does state that each owner owns a single car, if that's what you are referring to. My work should also have calculated the probability of filling the three cars with 12 people in a way that should leave only one slot in each car for an owner.